# Spring MVC - Error 404 with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity when testing Controller using @WebMvcTest

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc-test, springmockito, jsr250

We are trying to add unit testing to our Spring project `Controllers` (BTW, the Integration tests work fine), but we are suffering a very odd behavior, When we add the Configuration with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` (with JSR-250 annotations) if the Controller implements an interface (whatever interface) the `Controller` is not included by Spring application context as "request handler" (I checked it on method: `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(String beanName)`), that is, the requests mappings defined in the Controler (`@PostMapping`, ...) are not registered as potential locations, but if the interface is removed, then the Controller and the path is found without problem.

This is my Controller (simplified) with a simple interface `MyInterface`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/customer")
@RolesAllowed({Role.Const.ADMIN})
public class CustomerController implements MyInterface {    
    @Override // The only method in MyInterface 
    public void myMethod(Object param) throws QOException {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }    
    @PostMapping(path = {"/", ""})
    public Customer create(@RequestBody Customer data) throws QOException {
        return customerService.create(data);
    }
}
```

And this is the Test class (if I remove the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` config class all works fine):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = CustomerController.class)
@Import({ CustomerController.class, TestAuthConfiguration.class, TestAuthConfiguration2.class})  //, TestAuthConfiguration.class })
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "unittest"})
@WithMockUser(username = "test", authorities = { Role.Const.ADMIN })
class CustomerControllerTest {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(CustomerControllerTest.class);
    @EnableWebSecurity
    protected static class TestAuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            LOG.info("configure(HttpSecurity http) ");
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().filterSecurityInterceptorOncePerRequest(true)
                    .antMatchers("/api/session/**").permitAll() //
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() //
                    .anyRequest().permitAll().and() //
                    .addFilterBefore(new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                        @Override
                        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                            if (auth != null) {
                                LOG.info("User authenticated: {}, roles: {}", auth.getName(), auth.getAuthorities());
                            }
                            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                        }
                    }, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }

    }

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, securedEnabled = false)
    protected static class TestAuthConfiguration2 extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
            return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(""); // Remove the ROLE_ prefix
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testCreate() throws Exception {
        Customer bean = new Customer();
        bean.setName("Test company");           
        when(customerServiceMock.create(bean)).thenReturn(bean);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/customer") 
        .content(JsonUtils.toJSON(bean)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.name").value("Test company"));
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is happeing, I've tried to find an example of unit testing in controllers with security based on anotations JSR-250 (@RollesAllowed), but I didn't find anything useful, anyway this problem sounds (to me) to a bug, but I'm not sure, so any help is welcome.

The libraries versions:

- Spring Boot version: 2.2.2
- Spring Core: 5.2.1
- Mockito Core: 3.1.0

Comment: I faced a similar issue and solved it by adding proxyTagerClass as true to get it working. @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `proxyTargetClass` attribute to `true`. I was facing a similar problem and solved it by adding this.

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Also i would recommend reading javadocs for `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` especially paying attention to `proxyTargetClass` and `mode` attributes.